# Cannot create a linux partition in GParted because of warnings and minimum size and maximum size are the same

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, windows-10

I have a 64 bit system with a 500 gb hardrive and 8 gb of RAM.
I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Windows 10. I used universal USB installer to mount GParted live 0.28.1amd64 and when i boot it up i saw two warning icons beside my windows partition and when trying to create a linux partition, the maximum size and the minimum size allowed is the same. One of the warning messages i receive reads:

Unable to read the contents of this file system! 
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package. 
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs
file system support: ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs

A link to the image is given below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucyxj.jpg

Another warning message beside an unknown partition reads

Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are: 
- The file system is damaged 
- The file system is unknown to GParted 
- There is no file system available (unformatted) 
- The device entry /dev/sda3 is missing

A link to the image is below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l97Vw.jpg

Please help Ubuntu community! Ive been stuck on this for quite sometime and i really want to get back to learning programming and Ubuntu!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Instead of using GParted's own live image, try GParted from inside of Ubuntu's live image.

Comment: You should use an Ubuntu Live USB. It has gparted as well as ntfs-3g/ntfsprogs. Also, check [How do I install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

Comment: You also need to turn off Windows fast start up or always on hibernation. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Error on Microsoft reserved is ok as that is unformatted which looks like an error but is correct. But error on Windows partition says you left hibernation on.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **always shrink/extend NTFS partitions using Windows own Disk Management application**. Use **gparted to manage EXT4/swap partitions**.

When using the Windows Disk Management application, if you can't shrink your Windows partition enough, it's probably because of an unmovable file like a swap or hibernation file. You'll temporarily need to disable swap, *you may have to reboot here*, defrag, and then retry the shrink operation. Remember to re-enable swap when you're done.

Second, the caution sign that you see in gparted beside sda3 and sda4 *may* be solvable, at least for sda4. Check to make sure that ntfs-3g is installed. It probably is already.

In `terminal` type:

- `sudo dpkg -l ntfs-3g | grep ii`
- if you get no result from this command, then you don't have it installed, and you probably should install it...

  - `sudo apt-get update`
  - `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

If you're goal is to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu, you'll want to do this to disable `fast startup` and `hibernation`:

In Windows:

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C: